# starting an activity crashes

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a service and a listener to locations notifications.
When a location notification is received, I want to start an activity.
The call to startActivity, crashes every time, and I do not understand why?

How can I do this?

my Service:

```
public class MyService extends Service {
    private Looper mServiceLooper;
    private ServiceHandler mServiceHandler;

    private final class ServiceHandler extends Handler {
        public ServiceHandler(Looper looper) {
          super(looper);
        }
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) 
        {
          synchronized (this) 
          {
            Bundle data = msg.getData();
            handleRequest(data);
          }
        }
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    HandlerThread thread = new HandlerThread("OpenAppThread");
    thread.start();
    mServiceLooper = thread.getLooper();
    mServiceHandler = new ServiceHandler(mServiceLooper);
...
```

My location notifier

```
public class LocationNotifier implements
    GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
    LocationListener {

    private MyService mContext;

public void onLocationChanged(Location locationHere)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, AnotherActivity.class);
    mContext.startActivity(intent);  // This Crashes !!!
```

Comment: Likely because mContext = null. Do you ever pass your context to your LocationNotifier class?

Comment: you forgot to post the most important part: the logcat output

Comment: @zgc7009 is probably right. If so, you should be receiving a NPE in your method.

Answer (score 0):

1.- Check if your context is different to null.
2.- Check if your activity is registered in the manifest.
3.- Check if the onLocationChanged is a infinite bucle.

If you can copy and paste the logcat, that is a information useful to we can help you.